# how can i solve "ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

Im getting this error installing oracle client-server at the same time
how can i solve it?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it

Answer (score 1):

In the connection you show, you have not specified the name of the database you want to connect.  Therefore, it is using the value indicated by the environment variable ORACLE_SID.  Furher, it uses that as a value to connect to a *local* datatabase - a database running on the same machine as the requesting client.  The error your report is most commonly resulting from ORACLE_SID *not* indicating a valid instance name for a *local* database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your $PATH environment variable has the path to the server the first one. Like this.

For checking it go to *This PC* (right-click) -> *Properties* -> *Advanced System Settings* -> *Environment Variables* -> *System Variables*.

Solution here:

[image: Solution here]